# SharePoint 2013 workflow send an email when an list item is changed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a basic workflow so that when any item value in the "System Security Status" column is changed to "Gone", I will be notified by an email. It is really basic, but I came into an issue where when there's 5 items that have the "System Security Status" columns changed to "Gone", I receive five duplicate emails.

Would you please instruct me on how to make the change so that, even if multiple items are changed, I will receive one instead of multiple duplicate emails. It would be even more wonderful if the items that have been changed are displayed in the email body.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is impossible to send summary email for all changed items using SharePoint Designer Workflow.

For sending one email for multiple items, you can create a timer job and run this timer job daily. Query the items which are meet the conditions ("system security status" column is changed to "Gone") in the list, then send the email.

Or you could using PowerShell to check items and send email, schedule PowerShell script in Task Scheduler to automatically run it at a schedule time.

[How to create a timer Job](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/how-to-create-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer; i did consider creating a timer job, but it requires server side coding/configuration, so as an end user, I will not be able to do that. I will check my company SharePoint admin on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Designer, you can create a simple workflow in that list:

1.Open the list in SharePoint Designer and click "List Workflow" in the top left.

2.Add a Condition, "Modified by a specific person", select the user.

3.Add a Action "Send a Email".

4.In workflow setting and click both "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed and created"

Answer (score 0):

While you can send the item details in email body, you cant stop it from sending emails for each item changed. You can achieve it with different methods like Timer job etc which Joanna explained above.

You can send items details in email body by "Send a Email" Action in workflow. It will open you the body window which will allow you to put the fields of current item!